# How to save canvas into database

Tags: javascript, php, database, html5-canvas

Im doing a project which is web based abc tracing program.In my program,i should have a save button which will convert the drawing in canvas into image any automatically save the image in database.I dont know how to do this.I can convert the drawing into image but i dont know how to save into database.

This is my coding
html

```
<html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display+SC:700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssdrawing.css">
<script src="a.js"></script>
<body>

<div style="background:A5F0FA;padding:10px;padding-bottom:20px">
<h1 style="font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;text-align:center;margin-bottom:10px">Lets Trace!</h1>

<hr style="margin-bottom:15px;padding-top:0px;" width="500px" />
<center>
<div align="center" id="MainDiv"  style="background:#FAA5EE;box-shadow:5px 5px 5px silver;padding:10px;max-width:90%;">

<canvas id="painter" height="300px" width="500" style="background: url('./images/vtr.jpg')"></canvas>

<br />
<div class="holder">
<span>Colors:</span>
<input type="button" style="background-color:FF0000;padding:10px 24px" onclick="Color('red')"></button>
<input type="button" style="background-color:0000FF;padding:10px 24px" onclick="Color('blue')"></button>
<input type="button" style="background-color:DE5616;padding:10px 24px" onclick="Color('brown')"></button>
<input type="button" style="background-color:FFFF00;padding:10px 24px" onclick="Color('yellow')"></button>
<input type="button" style="background-color:008000;padding:10px 24px" onclick="Color('green')"></button>
<input type="button" style="background-color:DE168F;padding:10px 24px" onclick="Color('pink')"></button>
<input id="color" type="color" onclick="Color(this.value)" onchange="Color(this.value)"></input>
<br /></div>
<div class="holder">
<span>Thickness:</span>
<input value="30" id="number" min="30" max="100" type="number"></input><br /></div>


<div class="holder">        
<span>Other:</span>
<button onclick="Color('white')">Eraser</button>
<button onclick="ClearCanvas()">Clear Canvas</button>


<a id="download" download="img.jpg"><button type="button" onClick="download()">Save</button></a>
</div>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function Color(a) {
        var offset = function(obj) {
            var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
            if (obj.offsetParent) {
                do {
                    curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
                return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
            }
            return undefined;
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById("painter");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var draw = false;
        var pos = offset(canvas);
        canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (draw == false) { return; }
            var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
            var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
            console.log(x,y);
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            context.stroke();
        }
        canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
            draw = true;
            var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
            var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x, y);

            context.lineWidth= document.getElementById("number").value;
            context.strokeStyle=a;
        }
        canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
            draw = false;
        }
        }
function ClearCanvas() {
var c=document.getElementById("painter");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0,0,880,300);
}

function Preview() {
var canvas  = document.getElementById("painter");

var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

window.open(dataUrl, "", "width=880, height=300");
}


function download(){
        var download = document.getElementById("download");
        var image = document.getElementById("painter").toDataURL("image/jpg")
                    .replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream");
              download.setAttribute("href", image);
              //download.setAttribute("download","archive.jpg");
              $.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'photo_upload.php',
  data: {
    photo: photo
  }
});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Send that dataUrl back to your server with an AJAX post

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "photo_upload.php",
  data: {photo : dataUrl}
})
.done(function(respond){console.log("done: "+respond);})
.fail(function(respond){console.log("fail");})
.always(function(respond){console.log("always");})
```

On the PHP side, save the incoming dataURL to a database:

```
<?php

$sql="insert into table_name(photo) values(:photo)";

// INSERT with named parameters
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', "root", "myPassword");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":photo",$_POST["photo"]);
$stmt->execute();
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $affected_rows;

?>
```

Comment: where to add this coding?

Comment: Modify ur jQuery and php script with my script

Comment: if you dont mind,can i know how many column shud i create in my databse?